# How can I play games requiring DirectX in linux?

Tags: linux, directx

I am an avid gamer, I use Windows & Linux, I would like to play games in my Ubuntu machine which requires **DirectX**.

How can I run the game which requires DirectX in Linux?

Comment: Please ask just one question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

> Wine lets you run Windows software on other operating systems. With Wine, you can install and run these applications just like you would in Windows.

Here is the [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/) where you can check how well an application/game works with wine.

Here is an introduction article on [How to install DirectX in Linux](http://www.dedoimedo.com/games/wine-directx.html)

---

Then there is [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) a commercial product that I have used in the past with decent results.

Comment: @Nifle : your answer should be updated for Direct3D 12 *(unlikely to get converted to OpenGl like prior versions)*.

Comment: @user2284570 - Feel free to edit the answer yourself. I'm too out of the loop now.

Comment: @Nifle I don't have the edit privilege, and your post is not community wiki.